# Appear and disappear effect with camera movement

Tags: video, video-editor, editing, effects

I was watching a Lil Skies music video produced by Cole Bennett and noticed an effect. It had Lil Skies singing in front of a car, and he would vanish and the car would also vanish and reappear at random times. It seems like an easy task if it was shot on tripod and then masked/layered, but with all the camera movement it makes me curious as to how its pulled off. Perhaps where its shot in 4k he just blew up footage in post and made artificial movement while still keeping it 1080p? For anyone curious the video is [Lil Skies - More Money More Ice](https://youtu.be/qLgPQtfEvJU?t=4) and the scene is early in video.

Answer (score 1):

That is simply greenscreen compositing.

These days it is relatively easy to track a camera movement from a random video clip, you can for example film the yard and composite a 3D car over it.

On this case, I would film the person on a green screen room with markings and even render the yard itself.

---

One more complicated way to do it would be a robotic arm controlling the camera, some can even receive the movement from another source, for example, tracking from a handheld camera. The movement can be repeated several times, one with the car other without it.

But the equipment would be more sophisticated and expensive. I would go for the green screen and Blender.